# retrieve unique values from string of numbers

Tags: vb.net

i have this string

```
 Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"
```

and want to retrieve a string

```
newstr = 12,32,15,16,14
```

i tried this much

```
Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"
Dim word As String
Dim uc As String() = test.Split(New Char() {","c})
For Each word In uc
' What can i do here?????????
Next
```

only unique numbers how can i do that in vb asp.net

right answer

```
Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"
                Dim word As String
                Dim uc As String() = test.Split(New Char() {","c}).Distinct.ToArray
                Dim sb2 As String = "-1"
                For Each word In uc
                    sb2 = sb2 + "," + word
                Next
                MsgBox(sb2.ToString)
```

Comment: mvccarl i am getting this error with your solutions Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"
Dim uniqueList As String() = test.Split(New Char() {","c}).Distinct().ToArray()
```

Comment: He required the solution to be in VB.NET not C# but your are right that would work in C#

Comment: Distinct is not a member of System.array

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"
    'Split into an array
    Dim testArray As String() = test.Split(",")
    'remove duplicates
    Dim uniqueTestArray As String() = testArray.Distinct().ToArray())
    'Concatenate back to string
    Dim uniqueString As String = String.Join(",", uniqueTestArray)
```

Or all in one line:

```
   Dim uniqueString As String = String.Join(",", test.Split(",").Distinct().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Sorry I forgot to add the new string together

**Solution:**

```
Dim test As String = "12,32,12,32,12,12,32,15,16,15,14,12,32"

Dim distinctArray = test.Split(",").Distinct()

Dim newStr As String = String.Join(",", distinctArray.ToArray())
```

**Training References:** Check out this website for a guide on LINQ which will make these types of programming challenges easier for you. [LINQ Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84521/LINQ-for-the-Beginner)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put parentheses for Distinctand ToArray. Because these are methods

```
Dim uc As String() = test.Split(New Char() {","c}).Distinct().ToArray()
```