# Eliminate Duplicate from a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have Textbox1.Lines (separated by a space)

```
5 7 10 12 12
7 10 12 13 14
8 10 14 15 19
12 13 14 15 19
21 23 27 29 50
51 53 55 78 80
1 1 7 14 19
2 4 7 8 10
```

How should I remove duplicates from each line and display something like this:

```
  7 10 12 13 14
  8 10 14 15 19
   12 13 14 15 19
  21 23 27 29 50
  51 53 55 78 80
  2 4 7 8 10
```

that is, to remove from the entire line that contains a duplicate number on the same line.

```
Private Sub BttGamblerInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttGamblerInput.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim value As Integer
    Dim values As New List(Of String)
    For Each strValue As String In TxtGamblerImput.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Integer.TryParse(strValue.Trim, value) Then
            values.Add(value)
        End If
```

Not worked.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each line In TxtGamblerOutput.Text
            Dim originalArray = TxtGamblerOutput.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim checkArray = originalArray.Distinct().ToArray() ' I haven't used this, so check syntax etc when you code it.
            If originalArray.Length = checkArray.Length Then
                TxtGamblerOutput.Text = checkArray
            Else  ' <-- perhaps a bonus here?
                ' Do something with the invalid line
            End If
        Next line
    End Sub
```

Code 3:

```
   Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4, 8}

        ' get the duplicates
        Dim dups As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) ' number, count of number
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            If dups.ContainsKey(numbers(i)) Then
                dups(numbers(i)) += 1
            Else
                dups.Add(numbers(i), 1)
            End If
        Next

        ' display them
        For Each dup In dups
            If dup.Value > 1 Then
                Console.WriteLine(dup.Key)
            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Remove in a Multiline (1,2,3,4,4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936083/duplicate-remove-in-a-multiline-1-2-3-4-4)

Comment: Also you posted this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933346/eliminate-duplicate-from-a-textbox

Answer (score 2):

I haven't coded or tested anything, but you can use the `Distinct` method from `List(of T)` and compare the length of the output to the current List. Another approach is to use an ArrayList (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428210/9101981 for the bones of getting unique elements).

Pseudo-ish Code using an Array:

```
for each line in the text input
    originalArray = line.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    checkArray = originalArray.Distinct().ToArray() ' I haven't used this, so check syntax etc when you code it.
    If originalArray.Length = checkArray.Length then
        ' Your code here to display the valid line
    Else  ' <-- perhaps a bonus here?
        ' Do something with the invalid line
    End If
Next line
```

Some additional reading:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8
  and, in particular, note the recommendation to use `List`.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8
  noting that this is the Linq Distinct documentation

Comment: Not worked... I Edited my post :( how can fix that code for worked?

Comment: @EugenEnea: "not worked doesn't give us much to go on - what didn't work, did you get any error messages, what was your output and how did it differ from what you expected. However, this is a new question - start a new question with the specific code that your are trying with the above information.

Comment: @EugenEnea: also - what I provided above was pseudo code and is not expected to work directly - you have to do a little bit of work to change what I wrote into working VB.